# How do I prevent a WinMo phone from going into sleep when connected to PC?

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm working on an application which communicates with a PDA (windows mobile) through USB. After updating the PC to Win 7 and WMDC the connection fails after 30 minutes. This didn't happen in older versions (Active Sync). How can I prevent the phone from going into sleep mode after 30 minutes? I want to do this from the PC app, not by changing the power setting on the phone.

thx!